# Set default property for all controls of given type

Tags: c#, wpf

Say, I'd like to make all Scrollbars background property be Red by default.

I want the effect be similar to the result of this xaml:

```
<ScrollBar Background="Red" />
```

Now, I'm writing this code somewhere in constructor of the app class:

```
Control.BackgroundProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ScrollBar),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Red,
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
```

And this doesn't work, the Scrollbar on the window is not Red in runtime, it is just normal.

I assume I'm doing something wrong here, but can't find out what exactly. Could someone point me to solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a default Style in your Application Resources:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reponse. But, maybe you know what is wrong with my approach? I see no reasons why it shouldn't work the same way.

Comment: There certainly is a default ScrollBar Style in the framework that sets the Background property, and a property value from a Style Setter has higher precedence than a default value from property metadata.

Comment: Sounds legit, I never really tried to check this thing against that precedence list. Thanks.